# Show Tax Amount in the Product page

Tags: product, magento-1, catalog, tax, sales

I'm trying to show the label "Tax amount: 40$" on my product page, just under the price, as this image[image: tax amount example]

I enabled in the System > Configuration > Sales > Tax
almost every display with "show including tax and without tax" and "Show tax in the total" in every tab but I still do not see it, just a double price with tax and without tax.
How could do like the image show?
Someone could give me some advice?

Thank you very much!
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25403845/1480397 but it looks like horrible code, so I would do it this way:

[Get the tax rate](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/19162/217) then calculate the tax amount with `\Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation::calcTaxAmount`